# Sums and differences of decimal numbers give a periodic number in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, sum

In my PHP code I have a variable that corresponds to the sum and difference of some values obtained ​​from a MySQL database. This is the code:

```
<?php echo $verifica = (($valoreEntrate + $valoreInCassa) - ($valoreUscite + $valorePagamentiInSospeso + $valoreDaLasciareInCassa + $valoreDaPortareACasa)); ?>
```

Here is values of all variables involved obtained with echo:

```
$valoreEntrate = 3837.67
$valoreInCassa = 612.10
$valoreUscite = 97.81
$valorePagamentiInSospeso = 0
$valoreDaLasciareInCassa = 617.80
$valoreDaPortareACasa = 3734.22
```

The value of  $verifica is:

```
$verifica = -0.0599999999995
```

Instead of -0.6 like I expected...
Can anyone explain why this value?
Thank you so much!!!
Bye...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because they are `float` types, and floats are not stored as exact numbers.  See [PHP's entry on float](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) for further information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! But there is some data type to store exact number like MySQL decimal type? In my php code I have to do many computation and it would be so boring if I had to do all the operations with BC Math Functions ... Thank you so much!

Comment: Use either the GMP functions (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) or the BC Math functions (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php), depending on what's available with your install of PHP.